# The child's keys don't get deleted when I delete the parent key

Tags: sqlite

I made a database via SQLite which looks like the following:

[image]

and I created a table called as `books` like this:

```
CREATE TABLE books (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "title-book" TEXT, witer TEXT, comment TEXT, "intro-img" TEXT, "avalable-count" integer, "total-count" integer, "publisher-id" INTEGER REFERENCES publisher (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, "category-id" INTEGER REFERENCES categories (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY ("publisher-id") REFERENCES publisher (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

When I delete a category that is a parent key for books `category-id` then I see books table having the child key rows that include that category didn't remove and they exist as they were like in the following pictures:

[image]
[image]

Comment: check that your sqlite version is newer than 3.6.9 and it has foreign keys enabled. Also the command "PRAGMA foreign_keys" should return 0 or 1 instead of "no data" if it's supported. More info on: https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

Comment: i tried this code:PRAGMA foreign_keys; and it returns 0;and i use this code too :PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON; for sure it is enable

Comment: 0 means it's supported but disabled (by default), so enable it and test again. Also, you need to enable it for each connection `Foreign key constraints are disabled by default (for backwards compatibility), so must be enabled separately for each database connection.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite 3.6.19 and older doesn't support Foreign Keys.
If you have a newer version you can check the support using:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys
```

If it returns "no data" it means there is no support installed (because it was compiled with SQLITE_OMIT_FOREIGN_KEY or SQLITE_OMIT_TRIGGER defined), while **returning 0 means "supported but disabled"** (default) and **1 means "supported and enabled"**.

You can enable at runtime using

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

Be aware this must be enabled for every database connection:

> Foreign key constraints are disabled by default (for backwards compatibility), so must be enabled separately for each database connection.

Also consider:

> It is not possible to enable or disable foreign key constraints in the middle of a multi-statement transaction (when SQLite is not in autocommit mode). Attempting to do so does not return an error; it simply has no effect.

REFERENCE: https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

Comment: that's work!
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
my problem was the PRAGMA foreign_keys was disabled.
my question changed to this one
I suppose to send this project to a customer if I should for each time do PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON; this code, how can ask him to do this from customer?! 
I want to my database works correctly in other systems
what should I do?!

Comment: If you have a config file that setup the initial database conection you could add it there so it's call everytime a db conection is started